# How do I increase the inmargin in beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

I would like to do two things

1. Increase the size of `inmargin` area (i.e., customize inner sidebar so that more contents could fit there)
2. Reduce the empty space between the title of `block` environment and the slide edge (from the example below, the title of `block` has too much of wasted space to its left which could be used to create more readable sentences)

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{structure}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\usecolortheme{crane}

\usefonttheme{structurebold}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
% Description list defaults

    % To change font
    \newcommand{\descriptionfont}{\fontencoding{T1} \fontfamily{bch} \selectfont}

    % Label indentation
    \newcommand{\descLabOffset}{\widthof{\hspace{2.6mm}}}

    % Left of description aligned with the left margin
    \newcommand{\descLeftLabMarInd}{0mm - \descLabOffset}

    % Left of description aligned with \parindent
    \newcommand{\descLeftLabParInd}{\parindent - \descLabOffset}

    % Set the list options
    \setlist[description, 1]{font=\descriptionfont, leftmargin=*, labelsep=3mm, labelindent=\descLeftLabMarInd, align=left}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Induction Motors}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common?}

        Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons

        \begin{description}
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the `inmargin` can be changed with `\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=.5\paperwidth}`. Unfortunately the width of the block title is hard coded, but with the following redefinition the width can be adjusted:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=.5\paperwidth}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamer@putleft[2]{%
  \hbox to 0pt{\hss\vtop{%
      \normalsize%
      \@tempdima=\beamer@leftsidebar%
      \advance\@tempdima by-3ex%
      \hsize=\@tempdima%
      \leftskip=0pt plus 1fill%
      \rightskip=0pt\relax%
      \leavevmode#1}\kern#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Induction Motors}

    \begin{block}{Why is induction motor very common?}

        Induction motors are very practical for the following reasons

        \begin{description}
            \item[Rigid] Rigid
            \item[Cheap] Cheap
            \item[Low Maintenance] Low Maintenance
            \item[Self-Starting] Self-starting
            \item[No Excitation Needed] No Excitation Needed
        \end{description}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: don't use `enumitem` with beamer, beamer has its own mechanism to control the appearance of items.

**EDIT:**

I opened a PR to automatically adapt the text width to match the width of the sidebar (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/pull/529). Until this is fixed, you can get a patched version of the theme from https://github.com/samcarter/beamer/blob/c9672255bd7cfe45d67ff63e2305d48c213766d2/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemeinmargin.sty